# FOSS 2D game engine to make Android/iOS games that compiles to native

Tags: android, open-source, ios, game-development, web

I'm looking for a (foss) 2d game engine to make android/iphone/(optionally html5) games with that compiles to native. Looking for more of an engine than framework to do the heavy lifting, and my target games are in the casual mobile category. Because this is a spare time project, hoping to use an engine that is mostly feature complete so I can just make games, not worry about missing features.

*I've found Haxflixel, Love2d and Murl Engine. As a C#/Javascript programmer I find the syntax of Haxe and Flash Develop very intuitive and I'm leaning that way, but what say you? Experiences and recommendations from the community are highly valuable (not just looking for a list of engines but rather why it should be considered)*